# Select Second child and attribute an ID - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I attribute an ID to the second **gs-title**?

I try this, but doesn't work:

```js
var stopInterval = false;
var interval = setInterval(function($Document) {
    if(!stopInterval) {
       $("div > gs-title:nth-child(2)").attr("id",'pweb');
        stopInterval = true;
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
 },12000);
```

[image: Picture Here of all code]

** Resolved **

Second problem:

My automatic click doesn't work to, here's the code:

[image: Click Code]

Comment: `gs-title` should be `.gs-title`

Comment: still doesn't work @TerryWei

Comment: `$("div > gs-title:nth-child(2)")` should be `$("div > .gs-title:eq(1)")`

Comment: `document.getElementById("pweb").click()` or `$("#pweb").click();` `getElementById` doesn't need the hash(#)

Comment: @TerryWei doens't work, here is the code: [link](https://pastebin.com/f8UcaQJ3)

Comment: use `document.getElementById("pweb").click()` instead to trigger the native click event

Comment: @TerryWei still doesn't click

Comment: Does your browser block new tab?

Comment: @TerryWei No, I have pop-ups allowed, here is the all code: [link](https://pastebin.com/dAK7TsAd), im working on this website: [link](https://codigopostal.ciberforma.pt/resultado-da-procura2/?termos=instituto+superior+de+engenharia+de+coimbra)

Comment: @TerryWei works when i use on Chrome Console, maybe a error on loop?

Comment: @TerryWei problem solved! Thanks mate!

Comment: OK great job dude

Answer (score 0):

Use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$("div > .gs-title:eq(1)").attr("id",'pweb');
```

**EDIT**

```
$("#pweb").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exmple:

```js
var stopInterval = false;
var interval = setInterval(function($Document) {
    if(!stopInterval) {
       $("div > .gs-title:eq(1)").attr("id",'pweb');
        stopInterval = true;
        document.getElementById('pweb').click();
        // or $('#pweb').click();
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
 },12000);
 
 $('a').click(function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).html());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <a class="gs-title">1</a>
    <a class="gs-title">2</a>
    <a class="gs-title">3</a>
    <a class="gs-title">4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture of your code I think you are trying target a.gs-title which is inside div.gs-title, for this you can simply change `div > gs-title:nth-child(2)` to `a.gs-title`

Comment: Exists a lot of gs-title inside "a", that why i need to use "div > .gs-title:eq(1)"

Answer (score 0):

```
let gs_elt = document.getElementsByClassName('gs-title');

Array.prototype.map.call(gs_elt,function(elt,index){
   //adding click event
   elt.addEventListener("click",function(event){
       alert('click event succeded');
   })

   //setting attribut to the second child
   if(index ==1){
       elt.setAttribute('id','second_child_attribut');
   }
})
```